# Are all females who are ajnabi, ajnabi?

Tags: halal-haram

My question is whether all ajnabis are ajnabis ?

This might seem confusing . So here's an example -

I went to my friend's house and he has a daughter of about 7 years of age who has obviously no yet become baligh / attained puberty.She is obviously not mahram to me .
Is it a sin if I pat her head ? Is she Ajnabi when she isn't a woman technically ?

Comment: In Islam, an individual is considered an adult on attaining puberty not before it.

Comment: What is "ajnabi"? In Islam there are mahrams and non-mahrams. You may be part of the family but still non-mahram. "ajnabi" in Arabic only means foreigner and is somewhat misleading in this context.